# How to redirect Rails old path to the new path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

So this is the path for all my users:

**http://localhost:3000/users**

I would like to change **/users** to **/members** , so I did this:

`get '/members' => 'users#index', as: "members"`

This way, people can visit **http://localhost:3000/members** and get all the same content in **/users** .

But the problem is that **http://localhost:3000/users** is still accessible to people. How can I remove/hide/redirect **/users**, so that people will see **/members** when they try to use this old **/users** url: **http://localhost:3000/users** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends on if you want to eliminate the path or simply override it

Since you mention that `http://localhost:3000/users` still maps somewhere, I'm going to assume that you have either the line `get '/users' => 'users#index'` or more likely something like `resources :users`. If you have the first line, simply delete it, if it's the second you can restrict the routes that you create with the `:except` option

`resources :users, except: :index`

For a redirect, the solution hamdi posted should work as well.

Check out rails routings page for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect like the below:

```
get '/users', to: redirect('/members')
```

Also you can find more info for redirection at the below link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection